# attribute information not being found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

When the button is pressed it states that the model is invalid as fields are empty. 
when looking at the model all fields are empty or null. anyone know how to solve this issue, thanks

Home Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> createOrderLine(Product models)
    {    
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.OrderLines.Add(new OrderLine
            {  
                productId = models.productId,
                productColour = models.productColour,
                productDescription = models.productDescription,
                productName = models.productName,
                productPrice = models.productPrice,
                productStock = models.productStock,
                //QuantityOrdered = quantityOrdered
            });

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "OrderLines");
        }

        else return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Home Index - Displays the product information to the screen

```
@foreach (var product in Model)
{

using (Html.BeginForm("createOrderLine", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { 
@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{

<div class="row">
    <div class="blog col-md-6">
        <div>
            <h1>Product Name</h1>
            <h2>@product.productName</h2>

            <div>


                <h3>Product Description</h3>

                <h6><i>@product.productDescription</i></h6>

                <br />
                <h3>Product Price</h3>

                <td>@product.productPrice </td>
                <br />
                <h1>Product colour</h1>

                <td>@product.productColour</td>
                <div></div>

                <br />
                <br />       

                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10"> 
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-buy" value="Add to cart" onclick="btnbuy_Click" />

                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    </div>
}
}
```

Comment: A form only submits the name/value pairs of its successful form controls, and your not generating any form controls. But you can only submit one form so why are you generating multiple `<form>` elements?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that none of your field are linked to the model they only display it so to fix this
you can simply add a hiddenfor field that links the product id in your page like so for each of your product :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(product.Id)
```

then fill the rest of the informations you need with the id that is gonna be passed to your controller as a parameter

exemple :

```
public ActionResult createorderline(Product ProductToAdd)
{
 // add your product or do your treatment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what are you trying to do, but Louis is right. If you are trying to pass values back, you have to `@Html.EditorFor()` or some other ways to pass back information to the server.

You could also use `@Html.HiddenFor(product.Id)` then inside your `Actionmethod` call the database to get the rest of the info regarding your product or you could use `JQuery` as well.

In this case I would only use the `@Html.HiddenFor(product.Id)` and have a `static` helper method that will map your `orderline` class from the `DB`.

```
public static Product GetProductById(int productId){
    return db.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId);
}
```

But again you could just add the `FirstOrDefault()` line inside your controller as you not mapping from a `ViewModel` to a business `Model`.